# Update Table from Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have the following tables in a database:

```
CREATE TABLE `CRUISE-RES` (
`cruiseid` INT,
`end-day` DATE,
`start-day` DATE
PRIMARY KEY (`cruiseid`)); 

CREATE TABLE `ROOM` (
`cruise-id` INT,
`price` FLOAT,
FOREIGN KEY (`cruise-id`));

CREATE TABLE `PROFIT` (
`cruiseid` INT,
`total` FLOAT);
```

With the following sample table inserts:

```
-- cruise table inserts
insert into `CRUISE-ID` (`cruiseid`,`start-day`,`end-day`)
values (1, '2022/01/01', '2022/01/05'), (1, '2022/01/05', '2022/01/10'), (2, '2022/01/05', '2022/01/10')

-- room table inserts
insert into ROOM (price,`cruise-id`)
values (5,1), (10,1), (25,2)
```

I also have the following function that shows the profit of each cruiseid based on the number of days in the CRUISE-RES * price per day.

```
SELECT c.`cruiseid`, sum(rm.`price`*(DATEDIFF(c.`end-date`, c.`start-date`))) AS 'total_profit'
FROM ROOM rm
JOIN `CRUISE-RES` c
ON rm.`cruise-id` = c.cruiseid
GROUP BY rm.`cruise-id`,'cruiseid'
```

How can I use this information on a trigger that updates the PROFIT table after each insert into CRUISE-RES table?

Comment: Any reason why you're basically asking the [same question posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001782/mysql-trigger-to-total-values-across-tables?r=SearchResults&s=1|9.6067) ? ... the original question is NOT closed, so it _can_ be edited to add more details/information. Double postings such as this are undesirable, and not likely to get answers any faster. You've not shown any attempt of creating a trigger yourself in either example.

Comment: You have problems other than creating a trigger https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=136d6577b1646204560dcf80853e059a fix these first.

Comment: And https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5aa512a34893007f79ec9c7ccdb3567